# FlurryAdListener implementation

Tags: android, ads, flurry

I  wish to implement flurry ads to my app but i get various errors in various ways i do it, i wish to implement it in a base activity and then display the ads in a activity brought up front (i am following the guide flurry provides with the SDK)

i would prefer if there is a way i could make a new class that implements the code and doesnt need to have the base activity edited

This is my base activity (i have removed all codes related to flurry at the moment)

```
package com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test.R;
import com.sahaab.muslimzone.main.CustomDrawerAdapter;
import com.sahaab.muslimzone.main.DrawerItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public abstract class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public ListView mDrawerList;  
    List<DrawerItem> dataList;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;   
    public CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    public CharSequence mTitle;
    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;   
    public TextView mActivityHeader; 
    public RelativeLayout frame;
    RelativeLayout mbanner;
 // Delay is in milliseconds
    static final int DRAWER_DELAY = 200;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());

        try
        {
            mbanner = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);

        }
           catch (NullPointerException ne){
        }

    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public Runnable openDrawerRunnable() {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        };
    }     

    public void BuildDrawer() {
        mActivityHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.app_header_name);

        // Initializing
        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer); 

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);  

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Location", R.drawable.ic_menu_mylocation));        
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences)); 
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Facebook Page", R.drawable.ic_menu_fb));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Contact Us", R.drawable.ic_menu_send));            
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Share", R.drawable.ic_menu_share));            
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Info", R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details));  
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Donate To Us", R.drawable.ic_menu_blank));           

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);        

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        frame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) 
        {
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
            {
                float moveFactor = (mDrawerList.getWidth() * slideOffset);

                frame.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);  


        ImageButton drawerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.qpaper_menu);
        drawerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
              mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
          }
        });             

        mActivityHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
              mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
          }
        });  

        try
            {        
                ImageButton drawerButtonside = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_drawer_arrow);
                drawerButtonside.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                  public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
                  {
                      mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                  }
                });  
            }           
                catch (NullPointerException ne){
            }

        try
        {        
            ImageButton locationbuttonside = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_location_button);
            locationbuttonside.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
              }
            });  
        }           
            catch (NullPointerException ne){
        }    

        try
        {        
            ImageButton searchbuttonquran = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_search_button_quran);
            searchbuttonquran.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
              }
            });  
        }           
            catch (NullPointerException ne){
        }   

        try
        {        
            ImageButton searchbuttoncalendar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_search_button_calendar);
            searchbuttoncalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
              }
            });  
        }           
            catch (NullPointerException ne){
        }         



        RelativeLayout textmuslimzone = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_header);
        textmuslimzone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
            launchActivity(MainActivity.class);
          }
        });             

        RelativeLayout texttimings = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_timing);
        texttimings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
            launchActivity(IqamahActivity.class);
          }
        });  

        RelativeLayout textquran = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_quran);
        textquran.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          { 
            launchActivity(InfoActivity.class);
          }
        });             

        RelativeLayout textcalendar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_calendar);
        textcalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
            launchActivity(InfoActivity.class);
          }
        });   

        RelativeLayout textqibla = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_qibla);
        textqibla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          { 
            launchActivity(InfoActivity.class);
          }
        });             

        RelativeLayout textiqamah = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_iqamah);
        textiqamah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
              launchActivity(IqamahActivity.class); 
          }
        }); 

        RelativeLayout texthadiths = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_hadiths);
        texthadiths.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
              launchActivity(InfoActivity.class);
          }
        });             

        RelativeLayout textstories = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_stories);
        textstories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
              launchActivity(IqamahActivity.class);
          }
        });        

        RelativeLayout textdua = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_dua);
        textdua.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
          {
              launchActivity(DuaActivity.class);
          }
        });            

    }

    private void launchActivity(Class<?> paramClass)
    {
      startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), paramClass));
    }    

    public void SelectItem(int possition) {      
        switch (possition) {  
        case 0:     
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder1.setTitle("Location");
            builder1.setMessage("How would you like to obtain your location?");
            builder1.setPositiveButton(R.string.auto_detect, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // create an auto_detect string

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Your code for the onClick
                }
             });
            builder1.setNegativeButton(R.string.set_location, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // create a set_location string
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Again some code for onClick
                }
             });
            builder1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_mylocation); // Have an icon in the pop up if you want. Remove line if you don't :P
            builder1.show();        
            break;
        case 1:
              startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class));             
              break;
        case 2:
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/533969810047241"));
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/MuslimZoneApp")));
            }          
            break; 
        case 3:
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          i.setType("message/rfc822");
          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
          try {
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
          } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }             
          break;              
        case 4:
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                localIntent.setType("text/plain");
                localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", getResources().getString(R.string.share_intent_subject));
                Resources localResources = getResources();
                Object[] arrayOfObject = new Object[1];
                arrayOfObject[0] = getString(R.string.muslimzone_url);
                localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", localResources.getString(R.string.share_intent_body, arrayOfObject));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_intent_subject)));
                break;                  
        case 5:
          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class));             
          break;   
        case 6:   
            AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder2.setTitle("Donation");
            builder2.setMessage("Please Pick Your Donation Option. ( 10 - 90 % of the donations will be donated to a charity )");
            builder2.setPositiveButton("Google Play Store", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // create an auto_detect string

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent locatIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.donation"));
                    startActivity(locatIntent);     
                }
             });
            builder2.setNegativeButton("PayPal", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // create a set_location string
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=SSS4364EUZSBL")));
                }
             });
            builder2.show();            


            break;                
        default:
              break;
        }


  }    


    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
          mTitle = title;
          mActivityHeader.setText(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
          // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
          // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
          if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
          }

          return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
          // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
          mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }    



    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                SelectItem(position);

        }
    }




}
```

and this is the activity i wish to display a ad on (once again removed all flurry related codes)

```
package com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity;

import java.util.List;

import com.flurry.android.FlurryAdListener;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAdSize;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAds;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
import com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test.R;
import com.sahaab.muslimzone.main.CustomDrawerAdapter;
import com.sahaab.muslimzone.main.DrawerItem;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends MyActivity {

    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public ListView mDrawerList;  
    List<DrawerItem> dataList;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;   
    public CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    public CharSequence mTitle;
    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;   
    public TextView mActivityHeader; 
    public RelativeLayout frame;
 // Delay is in milliseconds
    static final int DRAWER_DELAY = 200;


      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          BuildDrawer();

            Button localButton9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
//            localButton9.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_prayer);
            localButton9.setText(localButton9.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
            localButton9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
            });
            Button localButton10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_qibla);
//            localButton10.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_qibla);
            localButton10.setText(localButton10.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
            localButton10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
            });
            Button localButton11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_quran);
//            localButton11.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_quran);
            localButton11.setText(localButton11.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
            localButton11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
            });
            Button localButton12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_holidays);
//            localButton12.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_calendar);
            localButton12.setText(localButton12.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
            localButton12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
            });    


            Button localButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dua);
//            localButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_dua);
            localButton1.setText(localButton1.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
            localButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DuaActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
            });
            Button localButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_hadith);
//           localButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_hadith);
            localButton2.setText(localButton2.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
            localButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DuaActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
            });
            Button localButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_iqamah);
//            localButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_iqamah);
            localButton3.setText(localButton3.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
            localButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IqamahActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
            });
            Button localButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stories);
//            localButton4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_stories);
            localButton4.setText(localButton4.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
            localButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
              public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
              {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
            });              


            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(openDrawerRunnable(), DRAWER_DELAY);  
                  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                  editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
                  editor.commit();
             }    



      }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }


/****************************************************************************************************************************/
    /****************************************************************************************************************************/
        /****************************************************************************************************************************/





      @Override
      protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
          return R.layout.activity_main;
      }          

}
```

this is the first error i get in MainActivity once i implement the FlurryAdListener

```
The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method FlurryAdListener.onAdOpened(String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you implement  FlurryAdListener.OnAdListener, you need to have all methods listed in the following reference

http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/v3.2.0.rc1/android/interfacecom_1_1flurry_1_1android_1_1_flurry_ad_listener.html

Just add all the methods to your code, e.g.

```
   @Override
   public void onAdOpened (String adSpace) {
       Log.d("Flurry", "onAdOpened");
   }
```

and you won't have the error.

Comment: thnx, i just fixed right now :-/
the main thing i wanted was to not have to implement the FlurryAdListener for every activity
i figured out a fix for it with my base activity and etc